# How can I truly shut down ssh server?

Tags: debian, sshd

I disable the ssh server with `systemctl disable ssh` then reboot.
After reboot, I still can log into the remote server through ssh.
I use `systemctl status ssh` to check the server status and it is inactive.

```
$ systemctl -a | grep ssh
ssh.service                                               loaded    inactive dead      OpenBSD Secure Shell server
ssh@3-192.168.0.120:22-192.168.0.104:31079.service        loaded    active   running   OpenBSD Secure Shell server per-connection daemon (192.168.0.104:31079)
system-ssh.slice                                          loaded    active   active    system-ssh.slice
ssh.socket                                                loaded    active   listening OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
```

How can I truly shut down ssh server?

Comment: You can simply uninstall `openssh-server`.

Comment: You seem to have more SSH-stuff installed than on average Ubuntu (checked my two Ubuntu 18.04 installation and got only the `ssh.service` line). Disable/uninstall what you don’t need.

Comment: Disable and stop the `ssh.socket` unit. It is used for socket-activated sshd.

Comment: FYI: `disable` on its own doesn't stop the running process ;)  you still need to disable the socket and stop the service.  As was stated in other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `stop` a service with `systemctl`, but you need to also `disable` it and anything that would cause it to start up.  You can use `systemctl disable sshd` so that `sshd` will not be started when you turn the system on in the future.  If I'm not mistaken, any existing `ssh` connections will be maintained even after running `systemctl stop sshd`.  No new connections should be able to become established.

You can see that with your `systemctl` command, you have `sshd.service` and `sshd.socket`.  You need to stop and disable both of these using `systemctl`, likely the socket first, and then the service.  One is dependent on the other and will not be disabled unless done in the proper order.

```
$ sudo systemctl stop sshd.service sshd.socket
$ sudo systemctl disable sshd.socket
$ sudo systemctl disable sshd.service
```

As it has been mentioned, Ubuntu's `openssh-server` only installs `ssh.service`, and no socket.  This is also true about Debian Stretch.  It seems you've deviated from default and without more details it's hard to know exactly what's going on.

Depending on the requirements, removing the package providing `sshd`  (`openssh-server`) would be a more fool-proof approach.  Please consider things such as the physical location of the machine, etc, before completely disabling `sshd` .